# Pickerview lag when updating labels

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm using a picker view, and want to update stuff on the screen relating to the item that is currently selected.

Here's the code from the program:

```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    TeamLabel.text = teams [row]
    attackField.text = "\(attacks [row])"
    defenseField.text = "\(defenses [row])"
    currentRow = row
    return teams [row]
}
```

This puts the team name, attack and defense values on the screen.

However, when scrolling the picker, I get the wrong result a lot. The text output doesn't match what's currently in the picker. Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you updating other UI elements inside the `titleForRow` picker view delegate method? This method should done one thing and one thing only - return a string.

Comment: OK. But how can I then update things based on what's currently selected?

Comment: Sure but you do that in the proper delegate method: `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`

Comment: OMgosh. I've just realized. It should be in didSelectRow, not titleForRow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong delegate method to update your text fields (or labels).

Update `titleForRow` to just:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return teams[row]
}
```

Then implement the `didSelectRow` delegate method to update your fields:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    TeamLabel.text = teams[row]
    attackField.text = "\(attacks[row])"
    defenseField.text = "\(defenses[row])"
}
```

Comment: Yep. Thanks very much.